# Restrict Azure WebApp to APIM through Managed Identity?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

I am wondering if it is possible to restrict access to an azure web app (it is functioning as an api, so I dont want public access just via the url) to API Manager through managed identity? Everything I can see is for using Azure HTTP Functions, not to a web app
Im assuming by doing so that users in the AD can also access the web app directly?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.
Your back-end API will need to check for either:

- An application permission (appRole) defined on the API app registration and assigned to the Managed Identity through PowerShell
- Or check that the object id in the token matches the Managed Identity

In the first option, other apps won't be able to use the API directly unless that permission is granted to that client application by an Application Admin/Global Admin.
The second option outright prevents other apps from using the API directly.
In both cases, you'll have [the API Management policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-authentication-policies#ManagedIdentity) get an access token targeting your API app registration.

Comment: this is the policy you might want to reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-authentication-policies#ManagedIdentity

Comment: Even though there have been few years on this answer, we tried the approach of defining app role and assigning it to managed identity. However, when the the APIM policy executes and adds the bearer token, if inspected, the bearer token does not contain roles claim, and the API subsequently prohibits access to the endpoint requiring a particular role claim to be present.

Comment: Could you find the API Management Managed Identity in Azure AD portal -> Enterprise applications, and check if Permissions tab lists the role?